# How do I detect the version of visual studio installed with a python script

Tags: python

The make system uses python. The autobuilders it is 10 but in development it is 11.0. It would be good to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this How-To](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx), then use [this from the standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) to read the specific keys.

Try:

```
import _winreg

key = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%s"

possible_versions = ["10.0", "11.0"]
installed_versions = []

for v in possible_versions:
    try:
        _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key%v, 0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        installed_versions.append(v)
    except Exception, e:
        pass

print installed_versions
```

This gives me

```
['10.0']
```

Comment: Saw this however I am new to python so struggled on how to check a key folder exists as the page shows 

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Setup\VS\<edition>

as the key to use. 

This does not exist on my PC with 11.0 install however Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version> does but it is a key name and I am unsure how to detect only the existence of a key name

Comment: Added a sample to do it. Pack it into some function and return `installed_versions`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Had to change to KEY_READ as the access was denied.